# WHILE loop to get 2 blocks of XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, for-xml-path

With T-SQL (I cannot use C# or any other scripting language due to application limitations) I am 'building' an XML message to post to a webservice.

A snippet within the XML message must be applied multiple times (depending on the amount of rows).

Below is a example of what I am trying to achieve:
I am creating a temporary table, put in two rows.

| row | numbers | crossingnumber | equipment | salesorder |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | UK22G1234567 | ST99999 | 00BJV1 | 12345-1 |
| 2 | UK22G8910112 | ST12345 | 00ABC2 | 67891-1 |

For each row I am trying to get a XML block with the information per row.
The expected result is:

```xml
<contentBody>
  <exportShipment>
    <customsDocument>
      <Type>IN</Type>
      <documentNumber>UK22G1234567</documentNumber>
    </customsDocument>
    <equipment>
      <equipmentNumber>00BJV1</equipmentNumber>
      <reference>ST99999</reference>
    </equipment>
  </exportShipment>
</contentBody>
<contentBody>
  <exportShipment>
    <customsDocument>
      <Type>IN</Type>
      <documentNumber>UK22G8910112</documentNumber>
    </customsDocument>
    <equipment>
      <equipmentNumber>00ABC2</equipmentNumber>
      <reference>ST12345</reference>
    </equipment>
  </exportShipment>
</contentBody>
```

For testing I am using the code below:

```sql
DECLARE @Counter INT, @MaxId INT, @number VARCHAR(50), @CrossingNr VARCHAR(50), @Equipment VARCHAR(50), @contentbody XML


DECLARE @tbl TABLE (row INT, numbers VARCHAR(50), crossingnumber VARCHAR(100), equipment VARCHAR(100), salesorder VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @tbl (row, numbers, crossingnumber, equipment, salesorder)  
    VALUES
    (1, 'UK22G1234567', 'ST99999', '00BJV1', '12345-1'),
    (2, 'UK22G8910112', 'ST12345', '00ABC2', '98765-1')

SELECT @Counter = MIN(row) , @MaxId = MAX(row) FROM @tbl
WHILE(@Counter IS NOT NULL AND @Counter <= @MaxId)
    
    BEGIN
        
        SELECT @number = numbers FROM @tbl WHERE row = @Counter
        SELECT @CrossingNr = crossingnumber FROM @tbl WHERE row = @Counter
        SELECT @Equipment = equipment FROM @tbl WHERE row = @Counter

        SELECT @contentbody = (
            (SELECT 
                (SELECT 
                    (SELECT 
                        "Type" = 'IN',
                        "documentNumber" = @Number
                    FOR XML PATH('customsDocument'), TYPE),
                    (SELECT 
                        "equipmentNumber" =  @Equipment,
                        "reference" = @CrossingNr
                    FOR XML PATH('equipment'), TYPE)
                FOR XML PATH('exportShipment'), TYPE)
            FOR XML PATH('contentBody'), TYPE)
            )
        
        SET @Counter  = @Counter  + 1        
    END

    SELECT * FROM @tbl
    SELECT @contentbody
```

So I am looping through the rows which is okay. But I am only getting the latest result, and I want to get both concatenated in some way.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I have *assumed* SQL Server here, however, if you are using a different product that uses T-SQL, such as Sybase, Azure Synapse, etc, then [edit] your question to correct the tag(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `WHILE`, you can just use a single `FOR XML`

```sql
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (row INT, numbers VARCHAR(50), crossingnumber VARCHAR(100), equipment VARCHAR(100), salesorder VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @tbl (row, numbers, crossingnumber, equipment, salesorder)  
    VALUES
    (1, 'UK22G1234567', 'ST99999', '00BJV1', '12345-1'),
    (2, 'UK22G8910112', 'ST12345', '00ABC2', '98765-1');

SELECT
  [exportShipment/customsDocument/Type] = 'IN',
  [exportShipment/customsDocument/documentNumber] = t.numbers,
  [exportShipment/equipment/equipmentNumber] = t.equipment,
  [exportShipment/equipment/reference] = t.crossingnumber
FROM @tbl t
FOR XML PATH('contentBody'), TYPE;
```

If you need each row as a separate XML document, you can do it in a correlated subquery.

```sql
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (row INT, numbers VARCHAR(50), crossingnumber VARCHAR(100), equipment VARCHAR(100), salesorder VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @tbl (row, numbers, crossingnumber, equipment, salesorder)  
    VALUES
    (1, 'UK22G1234567', 'ST99999', '00BJV1', '12345-1'),
    (2, 'UK22G8910112', 'ST12345', '00ABC2', '98765-1');

SELECT
  (
    SELECT 
      [customsDocument/Type] = 'IN',
      [customsDocument/documentNumber] = t.numbers,
      [equipment/equipmentNumber] = t.equipment,
      [equipment/reference] = t.crossingnumber
    FOR XML PATH('exportShipment'), ROOT('contentBody'), TYPE
  )
FROM @tbl t;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/rNnPLiFl)

Comment: This approach did not cross my mind, many thanks for this!